# Landlord returned part of security deposit, now wanting it back

Tags: rental-property, landlord, illinois

I recently ended my lease and moved.  When I handed over their keys, I did a walk-thru of the property with the landlord to document the damages.  He asked what I felt was fair and I reminded him that their terms of the lease gave him 45 days to return our deposit minus damages and asked if he wanted to get quotes.  He declined and we settled on an amount, summarized in writing via email and then he electronically transferred our remaining balance.

Now it is one week later.  I was contacted by him stating that the quotes were much higher than he anticipated and there was additional damage that was not noticed during the walk thru.  He now wants the funds returned to him.

Does he have any legal standing to make this request? Was the question of my liability settled when he agreed to return my deposit?

Answer (score 2):

### He is probably not entitled to any money from you

If the lease is typical, you are liable for any damage beyond “fair wear and tear”. This comes first from the security deposit but if this is insufficient you have to pay the extra.

The lease or tenancy law may provide a mechanism for valuing the damage and, if so, “by agreement” is likely to be part of it. Even if it isn’t parties can agree to vary the contract provided there is consideration on both sides - each of you foregoing your rights under the valuation clause would be adequate consideration.

Answer (score 0):

No, of course he can not force you to return the money.

The two of you agreeing on the amount satisfied the part of your rental contract concerning deposits.

"Revocation" is the legal word for rescinding a contract and it can only be done, before the deal is accepted or when a party fails to uphold the contract.
https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/revocation